# error defining computerChoice in the function getComputerChoice - javascript program

Tags: javascript

I am doing a simple rock, paper, scissors program in the codeacademy javascript course. This first one is very simple and much of what is here is the way they guided me. I know the entire thing can be written better but that comes later. Program works partially but never seems to define the computerChoice variable. I think the issue is in lines 15-18 but not sure.  I did try changing the strings to integers in lines 42, 49 & 58 but that did not solve the issue. 
Can anyone look at my code and offer guidance.

```
//function to get the user's choice
const getUserChoice = userInput => {
    userInput =
        userInput.toLowerCase();
    //if stmt to make sure input is valid
    if (userInput === 'rock' || 'scissors' || 'paper') {
        return userInput;
    } else {
        console.log('Invalid selection');
    }//end else
}//end getUserChoice function


//function to get computer choice
const getComputerChoice = () => {
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    //switch case to verify & return result
    switch (getComputerChoice) {
        case 0:
            return 'rock';
            break;
        case 1:
            return 'paper';
            break;
        case 2:
            return 'scissors';
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Invalid');
            break;
    }//end switch 
}//end getComputerChoice

//function to determine the winner
const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
    if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
        return 'The game is a tie';
    }


    if (userChoice === 'rock') {
        if (computerChoice === 'paper') { return 'You Won!'; }
    } // end userchoice is rock



    if (userChoice === 'paper') {
        if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
            return 'The computer won!';
        } else {
            return 'You won!';
        }
    } // end userchoice is paper


    if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
        if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
            return 'The computer won!';
        } else {
            return 'You won!';
        }
    } //end userchoice is scissors

}//end winner function


//function to play the game
const playGame = () => {
    const userChoice = getUserChoice('rock');
    const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    console.log('You threw: ' + userChoice);
    console.log('The computer threw: ' + computerChoice);

    //call funtion to determine winner
    console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
}//end playGame


//function calls
playGame();
```

Comment: Please post your gist on this site in your post, thanks

Comment: my apologies, I don't know exactly what that means.. create the gist then cut and paste the entire program in the message?

Comment: We should never need the entire program, unless it is literally only a few or several lines of code. What should really be presented here is a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is specific to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

After a more thorough examination, there were a few errors. **Demo 1** addresses each of these errors. **Details are commented in the demo.** There is a **[Plunker of Demo 1](https://embed.plnkr.co/8sRpgAw3WzJSvUuiDXAj/)** as well.

At first, I had started on a working demo without the benefit of your updated post. **Demo 2** is functioning as well and is helpful if you want to consider an alternative way to meet your objective.

## [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/8sRpgAw3WzJSvUuiDXAj/)

### Demo 1

```js
const getUserChoice = userInput => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  //if stmt to make sure input is valid
  if (userInput === 'rock' || 'scissors' || 'paper') {
    return userInput;
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid selection');
  } //end else
}; //end getUserChoice function


//function to get computer choice
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 On each case there was a return before every break
 A return statement always ends the block so break 
 was useless and in the process the switch useless.
      
 Changed getComputerChoice into a declared function
 Saved the results of switch in a variable
 Returned the value as expected
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
function getComputerChoice() {
  let compPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log('compPick: ' + compPick);
  var psr;
  //switch case to verify & return result
  switch (compPick) {
    case 0:
      psr = 'rock';
      break;
    case 1:
      psr = 'paper';
      break;
    case 2:
      psr = 'scissors';
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Invalid');
      break;
  } //end switch 
  return psr;
}
//function to determine the winner
const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return 'The game is a tie';
  }


  /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   Missing the else portion of conditional statement,
   Whenever user threw a rock and computer threw a
   scissor, the result was undefined.
     
   Added the else portion, now all 7 condition are met.   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
  if (userChoice === 'rock') {
    if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
      return 'You Lost!';
    } else {
      return "You Won!"
    }
  } // end userchoice is rock



  if (userChoice === 'paper') {
    if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
      return 'You Lost!';
    } else {
      return 'You won!';
    }
  } // end userchoice is paper


  if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
    if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
      return 'You Lost!';
    } else {
      return 'You won!';
    }
  } //end userchoice is scissors

}; //end winner function


//function to play the game
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 Added a <select> element so testing is properly done
 Changed playGame() to a declared function and the 
 callback function for the change event listener
 Note that playGame is passing a value. This value is from the <select>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
function playGame(psr) {
  const userChoice = getUserChoice(psr);
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  console.log('You threw: ' + userChoice);
  console.log('The computer threw: ' + computerChoice);

  //call funtion to determine winner
  console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
} //end playGame

/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 Reference the <select> tag
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
var sel = document.getElementById('psr');

/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 Register the change event on the <select> tag
 When change event occurs on select#psr, playGame() is 
 called and it passes the value of select#psr thru
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
sel.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  playGame(this.value);
});
```

```css
select,
option {
  font: inherit
}

#psr {
  margin: 30px 0 0 30px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <select id='psr'>
      <option>---</option>
      <option value='paper'>Paper</option>
      <option value='scissors'>Scissors</option>
      <option value='rock'>Rock</option>
    </select>

</body>

</html>
```

---

### Demo 2

```js
/* Using HTMLFormControlsCollection
\  Reference the form and...
*/
var game = document.forms.psrGame;

/* reference the form's form controls
 */
var ctrl = game.elements;

/* This is an Object Literal.
\  It's storing data for easy reuse
*/
var PSR = {
  player: 0,
  opponent: 0,
  action: ['Paper', '✂️Scissors', 'Rock'],
  outcome: ['Tied', 'Player Won', 'Player Lost'],
  won: 0,
  lost: 0,
  tied: 0
};

/* Register the click event on fieldset#set
\  Callback function is choice()
*/
ctrl.set.addEventListener('click', choice);

// Callback function
function choice(e) {

  /* if the clicked button (e.target) is NOT
  || the registered node (e.currentTarget)...
  || if the clicked node is a BUTTON...
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {

      // Get clicked button's id
      var z = parseInt(e.target.id, 10);
      PSR.player = z;
      //console.log('z: ' + z);

      // Get a randomly generated number 0-2
      var x = rand(0, 2);
      PSR.opponent = x;
      //console.log('x: ' + x);

      // Determine P.S.R. for player
      var pick = PSR.action[z];
      //console.log('Picked: ' + pick);

      // Determine P.S.R. for opponent
      var verse = PSR.action[x];
      //console.log('Verses: ' + verse);

      // Display P.S.R of player and opponent
      ctrl.choice.value = pick;
      ctrl.against.value = verse;
    }
    // Get the outcome and display it
    var us = determine(PSR);
    ctrl.view.value = us;
    return us;
  }
  /* Prevent event bubbling thereby isolating the
  || the click events from the rest of the form
  */
  e.stopPropagation();
}

/* Through a gauntlet of conditions
|| it is determined whether player
|| lost, won, or tied.
*/
function determine(PSR) {
  var Z = PSR.player;
  var X = PSR.opponent;
  var msg;
  if (Z === X) {
    msg = PSR.outcome[0];
    ++PSR.tied;
  } else if (Z === 0 && X === 2) {
    msg = PSR.outcome[1];
    ++PSR.won;
  } else if (Z === 1 && X === 0) {
    msg = PSR.outcome[1];
    ++PSR.won;
  } else if (Z === 2 && X === 1) {
    msg = PSR.outcome[1];
    ++PSR.won;
  } else {
    msg = PSR.outcome[2];
    ++PSR.lost;
  }
  /* This is a Template Literal which will
  || display the player's wins, losses, and ties
  */
  var totals = `Won: ${PSR.won}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lost: ${PSR.lost}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tied: ${PSR.tied}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`;
  ctrl.score.innerHTML = totals;
  return msg;
}

// Utility to generate random integers
function rand(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

#set {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input,
button,
output,
label {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block
}

button {
  width: 9ch
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-width: 30%;
  margin-left: 70%
}

#view {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: crimson
}

legend {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<form id='psrGame'>
  <fieldset id='set'>
    <legend>Paper, Scissors, Rock</legend>
    <button id='0' type='button'>Paper</button>

    <button id='1' type='button'>Scissors</button>

    <button id='2' type='button'>Rock</button>
  </fieldset>
  <label><b>Player:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
  <output id='choice'></output>
  </label>
  <hr>
  <label><output id='view'></output></label>
  <label style='float:right'><output id='score'></output></label>
  <hr>
  <label><b>Opponent:</b> 
  <output id='against'></output>
  </label>
```

Answer (score -3):

Line 18 should be

```
switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) {
```

Whatever value you pass to [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is what's compared against the values of the cases. The switch cases check a random integer from 0 to 2, so pass that generated random number to `switch`.

Comment: that worked. I thought I was setting computerChoice equal to the value of the Math.random string... thanks again